# What is Oracle's counterpart to SQL Server's @@IDENTITY?

Tags: plsql, sql-server-2008-r2, oracle11g

What is Oracle's counterpart to SQL Server's `@@IDENTITY`?

Comment: Since Oracle really doesn't have the concept of `IDENTITY` columns, it has no equivalent. In Oracle, you typically use a `SEQUENCE` to get consecutive, unique numbers for use in your tables.

Comment: answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51051121/3104267 helped me for my requirements as a work around for the equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Given that Oracle does not have identity columns, you would normally create a sequence for each table and use that sequence to populate the primary key.  Assuming you have done that, you can get the `currval` of the sequence to get the most recently generated sequence value for the current session.

```
SQL> create table foo(
  2    col1 number primary key,
  3    col2 varchar2(10)
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> create sequence foo_seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace trigger foo_trg
  2    before insert on foo
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.col1 := foo_seq.nextval;
  6* end;
SQL> /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into foo( col2 )
  2    values( 'foo' );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into foo( col2 )
  2    values( 'bar' );

1 row created.

SQL> select foo_seq.currval
  2    from dual;

   CURRVAL
----------
         2
```