# Oracle get id of inserted row with identity always

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, dml

Currently I have a table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "DUMMY_SCHEMA"."NAMES"
(
  "ID" NUMBER(10,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 20) NOT NULL 
, "NAME" NVARCHAR2(1024) NOT NULL 
, CONSTRAINT "NAMES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);
```

In SQL Server I only need to do following to get the Id of the inserted row.

```
INSERT INTO [NAMES]([NAME])VALUES('Random'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() Id
```

What would be the equivalent for Oracle 12c?

Comment: I'd recommend to use table and column names without "QUOTES": `CREATE TABLE dummy_schema.names (id NUMBER....` is the usual way...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equivalent is

```
INSERT INTO dummy_schema.names (name) VALUES ('Random') 
RETURNING id INTO :myvalue;
```

The mechanism how to pick up the returned ID depends on the host language (Java, PL/SQL, SQL*Plus etc).

Comment: Thanks. The variable :myvalue would be of what type?

Comment: Same datatype as your primary key column, in your case `NUMBER(10,0)`. What language are you using?

Comment: C# with dapper as ORM

Comment: Sorry, don't know, but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789737/dapper-and-oracle-crud-issues-how-to

Comment: thanks, finally made it work like you said!

Comment: insert into amalgam_care (id, name, activestatus, incorpcountry, sourcetable, sourcesystem)
select fund_id, fund_name, active, domicile, 'EMIS_FUNDS', 'EMIS' from EMIS_FUNDS  
where status in (2, 3, 4) and active = 1 order by fund_id           <- I have this query I want ID to be returned once inserted , how do i do this ? I have failed using above method   @wolφi

Comment: @SithijaPiyumanThewaHettige: Returned to where? Please have a look at the link in the question "This question already has answers here" to check if one of the answers suits you. BTW, I wouldn't use "order by" in an insert.